# ReportViewer Control Stops Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssas, reportviewer

I have a report viewer control like so :

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" style="margin-bottom:78px;" runat="server"
 AsyncRendering="true" SizeToReportContent="true" Width="100%" Height="100%"
 KeepSessionAlive="true"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

and the following two properties are changed in the C# code :

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue;
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
```

The issue is that the report viewer starts loading normally and randomly stops after about a minute or so. Now, there is a lot of data being retrieved from an OLAP Cube (around 100,000 rows) in the report trying to load. It is grouped with the expand / collapse functionality in SSRS. When I filter the data from the report it loads normally. The report also loads normally in Visual Studio 2012 as well on ReportManager (Takes a few minutes, but loads).

So my question is : **Is this too much for a ReportViewer Control to render or am I missing something?**

**Edit :**

The reason being for it to be grouped in SSRS is because by no means I am an expert in MDX. The MDX queries that I use are the ones automatically generated by SSRS. There is the MDX query generated (Changed the names of the columns, dimensions and measures) :

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Column1], [Measures].[Column2], 
[Measures].[Column3], [Measures].[Column4], 
[Measures].[Column5], [Measures].[Column6], 
[Measures].[Column7] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Dimension1].[Value1].[Value1].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dimension2].[Value2].[Value2].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dimension2].[Value3].[Value3].ALLMEMBERS * 
[TimeDimension].[Value4].[Value4].ALLMEMBERS * 
[Dimension2].[Value5].[Value5].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,   MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM 
( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DateParameter, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Monthly]) 
WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@DateParameter, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, 
STRTOSET(@DateParameter, CONSTRAINED), [TimeDimension].[Value].currentmember ) )
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, 
FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

It is grouped by

```
[Dimension1].[Value1].[Value1]
```

and by

```
[Dimension2].[Value2].[Value2]
```

In SSRS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does ReportViewer have anything like Paging..? can the query that loads or returns the data for the ReportViewer be refactored to return smaller record set..?

Comment: There is no paging whatsoever. The requirements and the layout of the report requires all the data to be there because there are some calculations made with it. Just a F.Y.I. it does not show 100,000 rows because it is grouped. There is maybe ~20 rows shown since there is so much data grouped.

Comment: perhaps you need to implement an alternative to using ReportViewer.. 100,000 rows sounds pretty heavy for a ReportViewer personally speaking

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Also yes, there is an alternative being discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably experiencing a timeout in ASP:

[ReportViewer timeouts in spite of timeout settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272394/reportviewer-timeouts-in-spite-of-timeout-settings)

I actually am working through similar issues myself at work right now. The only true solutions I have found (aside from the above link and consequently waiting for the report to render) are:

1. Very intense SQL / MDX performance tuning: Not always an option as sometimes datasets are optimal
2. Caching reports: Not always an option because some reports have too many possible parameterizeable possibilities.

I would try to run the report using the reportserver reportviewer and set the timeout to 0 for the report just to get a baseline of how long the report takes to run.

Then, run the following query:

```
use ReportServer

SELECT els.UserName
 , c.Name Report
 , els.Parameters
 , els.Status
 , els.Format   
 ,els.TimeStart
 ,els.TimeEnd
 , CAST(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND,TimeStart, TimeEnd)/60.0) as varchar(100)) + ''' ' + CAST(ABS( 60 * FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND,TimeStart, TimeEnd)/60.0)  -  DATEDIFF(SECOND,TimeStart, TimeEnd)) as varchar(100)) + '"' TotalTime
 ,CAST(FLOOR(TimeDataRetrieval/1000.0/60.0) as varchar(100))  + ''' ' + CAST(ABS(Floor(TimeDataRetrieval/1000.0/60.0)*60 - TimeDataRetrieval/1000) as varchar(100)) + '"' Data
 , CAST(FLOOR(TimeProcessing/1000.0/60.0) as varchar(100))  + ''' ' + CAST(ABS(Floor(TimeProcessing/1000.0/60.0)*60 - TimeProcessing/1000) as varchar(100)) + '"' Processing
 , CAST(FLOOR(TimeRendering/1000.0/60.0) as varchar(100))  + ''' ' + CAST(ABS(Floor(TimeRendering/1000.0/60.0)*60 - TimeRendering/1000) as varchar(100)) + '"' Rendering
 , els.[RowCount]
 , CAST(ROUND(CAST([RowCount] as decimal) / (CASE WHEN TimeDataRetrieval = 0.00 THEN NULL ELSE TimeDataRetrieval END /1000),2) as decimal(18,1))  RowsPerSecond
FROM ExecutionLogStorage els
LEFT JOIN Catalog c on c.ItemID = els.ReportID
WHERE c.Name IN( '<<REPORT NAME>>') AND
Format = 'RPL' AND
Status ='rsSuccess' AND 
1=1
ORDER BY TimeEnd DESC
```

And see where your report is spending the most time.

Also, do you mind providing your MDX query? It seems strange that you return 100k rows and then group them in SSRS. It's generally better practice to let MDX do your grouping / aggregation and calculate in calculated measures and then serve that to the report.

Comment: Thank you for your great and quick response. I edited the question with the query.

Comment: Looking at you query, I'm not sure you are using all of your dimensions in your report. Is the report tablix a matrix which groups on rows and columns? I think we can potentially remove some of the dimensions ([Dimension2].[Value3].[Value3],[TimeDimension].[Value4].[Value4],[Dimension2].[Value5].[Value5])  from your query that might not be needed and drastically improve your rendering times.

Comment: It is a tablix. For the columns to remove, I agree it would greatly improve the performance, but they are necessary to make some calculations required by the report. We are currently looking at an alternative to include those calculations into the Cube itself, so the detail does not have to be into the report (which is the issue). Thank you for your help.

Comment: That is indeed the issue. The real benefit of SSAS is its ability to aggregate and perform aggregate calculations quickly. Try creating calculated measures in the query designer and if you are having issues, please post a follow-up under the [SSAS] and [mdx] tags.